# Java - Future.get() multiple invocations

Tags: java, future

How does Java's `Future.get()` behave in the case where it is called multiple times after the task is completed?
Does it return the the same result? Or does throw an `ExecutionException` again and again with the same exception if the computation failed?
I can not find anything in the docs about it!

Comment: The [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) class docs (and [Future.get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--)) answer most of the questions - must have been reading something else.

Comment: And you could also try it and see by yourself.

Answer (score 41):

You can call `get()` on a `Future` as often as you like, and it will only block if the task that produces the result has not finished yet.

If the task has already finished, it will just immediately return the result of the task.

If the task has failed with an exception, calling `get()` will throw an `ExecutionException` each time you call it.

Answer (score 6):

> I can not find anything in the docs about it!

Have you read them ? because when I read them I got the Answer and here it is ....

> ```
> V get()
> throws InterruptedException,
>       ExecutionException
> ```
>
> **Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves**
>   **its result.**
>
> ```
> Returns:
>     the computed result
>
> Throws:
>     CancellationException - if the computation was cancelled
>     ExecutionException - if the computation threw an exception
>     InterruptedException - if the current thread was interrupted while waiting
> ```

If Computation is not completed it will wait , and if it has already completed it will return result ASAP , no matter how many times you call it

Comment: Where are you reading? in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--
I see:Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result. Without last part. Where you get that information? I not want to rely on undocumented behavior, I know what happens if I try, but I wanted the precise contract.

Comment: @MarcoServetto , So please read the line carefully , it will wait if process not completed or it will return result , It is not written anywhere that an exception will come if you call it repeatedly .`I get that Information by trying it, and then came to the conclusion`